# PyQGIS - is it possible to promote my own class in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qgis, pyqgis

While I developed QGIS plugin, I get some problem with promoting class in Qt Designer.

I create plugin, using Plugin Builder and after that I reorganize the structure to this:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OahNs.png)

So now, when I promote a ComboBox in Qt Designer to my combobox in src folder. In QGIS i have got that error massage.

```
2022-07-19T08:22:24     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
          plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "C:\Users/blank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\test\__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
          from .test import test
          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\Users/blank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\test\test.py", line 31, in 
          from .test_dockwidget import testDockWidget
          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "C:\Users/blank/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\test\test_dockwidget.py", line 30, in 
          FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\PyQt\uic\__init__.py", line 36, in __loadUiType
          return __PyQtLoadUiType(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 204, in loadUiType
          exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
          File "", line 29, in 
          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.2/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

My promoted widget in Qt Designer looks like that:

[Qt Promoted Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v20cU.png)

Maybe someone know how to write code to reparit it? Is it possible at all?
I wish to mention, when I developed some program outside QGIS i haven't got that problem

This is source code of QGIS plugin.

test_dockwidget.py

```
import os

from qgis.PyQt import QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import pyqtSignal

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(__file__), r'ui\test_dockwidget_base.ui'))


class testDockWidget(QtWidgets.QDockWidget, FORM_CLASS):

closingPlugin = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(testDockWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closingPlugin.emit()
        event.accept()
```

combobox.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QComboBox

class Combobox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.color)

    def color(self):
        print(self.sender(), self.currentIndex())
```

And of course test.py file, but it's so long and it's created by Plugin Builder so I don't paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I would say that making an empty file `__init__.py` in the `src` directory would solve the problem with python not being able to recognize `src` as module.

Comment: It wasn't working. I added src folder to path using sys.path in main plugin file.
Now everything is ok.